# How to write a $.getJSON call in $.ajax format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

While completing a project where I have to retrieve the user's long/lat using html5 geolocation and then a weather API to retrieve the weather at that location, I came across `$.getJSON` and `$.ajax`, and read the former is just shorthand for the latter.

They both look very different and I’m having trouble seeing how I would write my code below using `$.ajax()` instead of `$.getJSON()`. I’m hoping understanding how both work will help clear up some confusion I have about how to make API calls in general. I've read up on documentation regarding both but something just isn't clicking.

```
function showPoints(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    // AJAX request
    var api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=xxx";

    $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
                var kTemp = data.main.temp;
                var type = data.weather[0].description;
                var city = data.name;
                var country = data.sys.country;
                var tempSwitch = true;

                // temperature conversions
                var fTemp = (kTemp * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(0);
                var cTemp = (kTemp - 273).toFixed(0);
                $("#temp").html(fTemp + "&#176; " + "F");
                $("#temp").click(function() {
                    if (tempSwitch === false) {
                        $("#temp").html(cTemp + "&#176; " + "C");
                        tempSwitch = true;
                    } else {
                        $("#temp").html(fTemp + "&#176; " + "F");
                        tempSwitch = false;
                    }
```

Comment: They are not synonymous. `$.getJSON` expects the response to be JSON and parses it for you. `$.ajax`  does no such thing, at least not by default. Think of `$.ajax` as the common functionality of `$.get`, `$.post`, etc. Also, `$.getJSON` exists for a *reason*, don't replace it with calls to `$.ajax` without a good reason to do so.

Comment: @JaredSmith um, their documentation shows you what the $.ajax() equivalent is in the docs.... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @epascarello my point was merely that if you call `$.ajax` you *specify the options*, whereas `$.getJSON` is a call to `$.ajax` that specifies the options *for you*, and that there is no reason to do so manually.

Comment: It is personal opinion. I can open a window or I can make my kid open the window. Either way it gets opened.

Answer (score 3):

The `$.getJSON` function is just a shorthand, equivalent to this:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: success
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write `$.ajax()` for `$.getJSON` in below format

```
$.ajax({
  url: api,
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

`ajax` functions offer a wide bit of functions, 2 of the most used ones are `error` and `success`

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",  // or 'GET'
     url: api,
     cache: false,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
         // your success code here           
     },
     error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
     }
 });
```

You can also pass in data properties like so:

```
$.ajax({
     .......
     .......
     data: JSON.stringify({ yourObj }),
     // or use form data
     // data: $('#someForm').serialize(),
     .......
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This link [here](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2012/07/jquery-post-vs-get-vs-ajax.html) explains it in details. But basically you can't POST with $.getJSON. But with $.ajax, you can. Alternatively to POST you can use $.post

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax 
 First approach

```
    function showPoints(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    // AJAX request
    var api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=xxx";
                   $.ajax({
                        url: api, // url 
                        type: "GET", // type of action POST || GET
                        success: function (data) {
                              var kTemp = data.main.temp;
            var type = data.weather[0].description;
            var city = data.name;
            var country = data.sys.country;
            var tempSwitch = true;

            // temperature conversions
            var fTemp = (kTemp * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(0);
            var cTemp = (kTemp - 273).toFixed(0);
            $("#temp").html(fTemp + "&#176; " + "F");
            $("#temp").click(function() {
                if (tempSwitch === false) {
                    $("#temp").html(cTemp + "&#176; " + "C");
                    tempSwitch = true;
                } else {
                    $("#temp").html(fTemp + "&#176; " + "F");
                    tempSwitch = false;
                }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                            //console.log(xhr, resp, text+"................in error");
                        }
                    });
}
```